# How can I refresh the window with images in Python Kivy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

When I click on the buttons I want to see three images between two main images, but the program just waits 3 seconds and refresh the main images, I can't see the three others. The other images in the def rotate_room function, but the window won't load them.

```py
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.config import Config
from time import sleep

kivy.require('1.11.1')
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', True)
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '1280')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '720')

class Exhibition(App):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.img = Image(source="img/01.jpg", id="img")
        self.counter = 1
        self.f1 = FloatLayout()

    def build(self):    
        b_left = Button(text="<", id="b_left", size_hint=(0.15, 1), pos_hint={"left": 1},
                        background_color=(10, 10, 10, 0.1))
        b_right = Button(text=">", id="b_right", size_hint=(0.15, 1), pos_hint={"right": 1},
                         background_color=(10, 10, 10, 0.1))
        self.f1.add_widget(self.img)
        self.f1.add_widget(b_left)
        self.f1.add_widget(b_right)
        b_left.bind(on_press=self.change_img)
        Clock.
        b_right.bind(on_press=self.change_img)

        return self.f1

    def change_img(self, instance):
        if instance.id == "b_left":
            self.counter = self.counter + 1
            if self.counter > 4:
                self.counter = 1
            self.rotate_room()
            self.img.source = 'img/0' + str(self.counter) + '.jpg'
        if instance.id == "b_right":
            self.counter = self.counter - 1
            if self.counter < 1:
                self.counter = 4
            self.rotate_room()
            self.img.source = 'img/0' + str(self.counter) + '.jpg'

    def rotate_room(self):
        for i in range(1, 4):
            self.img.source = 'img/rot/01-' + str(i) + '.jpg'
            sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Exhibition()
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`time.sleep`'s function is, as the docs say, to "Delay execution for a given number of seconds". This isn't what you want, as drawing your changes to the gui is a part of the program's execution that you specifically do not want to delay.

Instead of using a loop with sleeps, use `Clock.schedule_interval` and/or `Clock.schedule_once` to schedule your updates within the program, without actually blocking it.